# how to calculate first monday of a x months in future with php

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I want to find the time for first monday after say 10 months, something like this:-

```
   $start = time();
   echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', $start), PHP_EOL;
   $start = strtotime('first Monday +10 month', $start);
   echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', $start), PHP_EOL;
```

The result is:-

```
Monday 13th of January 2014 08:04:28 AM
Thursday 13th of November 2014 12:00:00 AM
```

Why is the first string not applied?

Comment: _Why is the first string not applied?_ Which one?

Comment: I think he's referring on Monday.

Comment: Yup, the "first Monday" part doesn't seem to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code:

```
<?php
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', strtotime('first monday of +10 month'));
?>
```

And got the result -- all I had to do was add "of" to the string.  Notes on the site indicate this is for >=5.3.

Output:

```
Monday 3rd of November 2014 12:00:00 AM
```

**Edit** Ignore all this BS

It's because you missed the note [in the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).  It applies

> Relative statements are always processed after non-relative statements

So, it's going to the first Monday and then going forward 10 months.

**Edit:** Strike this: Change the order to `'+10 months first Monday'` to get what you desire.
I misread the note, too.  I guess it means you need to do 2 strtotimes in the order you need.

Comment: With '+10 months first Monday' , the output becomes 'Thursday 20th of November 2014 12:00:00 AM'

Comment: I just corrected myself... it says relative statements are *always* processed after, so you must break them up when calculating.

Comment: I'm not sure I actually *believe* my answer, so I'm going to test it and update the answer. I feel obligated since Iposted as an answer, lol